# How can I improve Legacy Logger Class by extending the constructor C#

Tags: c#, .net

Hi I have a Legacy code logger class that I want to extend the functionality without changing the original class. But it is badly written in my opinion and I am finding it difficult to figure out the best way to add new functionality to it

```
 public class DBLogger
    {
        public Exception FileImportError{ get;set; }

        public string FileName  {   get;set;     }
        public string Vendor   {     get;         set;    }
        public long FileSize  {   get;set; }
        public DateTime StartTime { get;set;     }
        public DateTime EndTime    {get;set;    }

        private ITraceabilityDatabase _database;

        public DBLogger(ITraceabilityDatabase database, Exception fileImportError, string vendor, string fileName, long fileSize, DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime)
        {
            _database = database;
            FileImportError = fileImportError;
            FileName = fileName;
            FileSize = fileSize;
            StartTime = startTime;
            EndTime = endTime;
            Vendor = vendor;
        }

        public void LogFileImportStatus()
        {
            string errorMessage = GetErrorMessage();
            string importStatus = GetImportStatus();

            if (!_database.InsertFileInfo(FileName, Vendor, FileSize, StartTime, EndTime, importStatus, FileImportError == null ? "" : FileImportError.Message))
            {
                EventLogWriter.WriteEntry("Failed to add file entry in database for " + FileName + Environment.NewLine + "Error: " + _database.GetLastError());
            }
        }
        private string GetImportStatus()
        {
            if (FileImportError != null)
            {
                if (FileImportError is PartialImportException)
                {
                    return "PARTIAL";
                }

                return "FAILURE";
            }

            return "SUCCESS";
        }

        private string GetErrorMessage()
        {
            if (FileImportError != null)
            {
                return FileImportError.Message;
            }

            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
`
```

1. So I need to add a new status of Duplicate.

To do this I want to add another field to the DB Logger constructor.

I have thought about constructor inheritance and adding a new constructor that will add the new status parameter then use the existing constructor to populate the other fields. thus reducing the lines of code. Like this.

```
public DBLogger(string status)this:(ITraceabilityDatabase database, Exception fileImportError, string vendor, string fileName, long fileSize, DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime)
    {
```

_status = status;
}

However I also want to reduce the arguments in the constructor by passing all the arguments in as a new class object. Any Ideas how I would modify my additional constructor to do this?

Comment: Nor sure I’m following. If you have the code, you can do whatever you want?